# Подсчёт времени выполнения методов

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Нужно померить время выполнения методов. написать так:

```
Stopwatch.Start();
Method();
Stopwatch.Stop();
```

не проблема.

Но возникает вопрос: можно сделать разумное логирование например так:

```
using(MyCustomProfiler p = new MyCustomProfiler())
{

    Method();
    Method2();
    ////////
    MethodN();
}
```

И что бы логировался каждый метод внутри `using`.

Может кто то знает элегантные решения, вместо использования `ContextBoundObject`, `IContextProperty`, `IContributeServerContextSink`, `IMessageSink`.

Если вдруг есть еще способ логировать вызовы внутренних вызовов методов, то это будет шикарно.

Нужно написать решение (код), а не использовать профайлер.

`StackTrace` и `StackFrame` тоже не очень подходят.

Comment: что бы каждый.. ничего кроме как реализаций как нибудь через отражения не могу придумать. ибо using-у совершено без разницы, он не для этого.

Comment: @AiSatan, во первых `using` это просто для упрощения использования. во вторых, Вы уверены в том что "отражения" могут предоставить средство для отслеживания `ВЫЗОВА` метода? На сколько я знаю reflection просто предоставляет доступ к метаинформации сборки.

Comment: не уверен, но пытаюсь Вам хоть как то помочь, ибо Вы отсеяли очень многое :) я подумал о атрибутах на каждом вызываемом методе, а как их динамический навесить не совсме представляю, поэтому подумал о отражениях

Comment: @AiSatan, если Вам интересно то, вот так это делается динамически: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35682/AOP-Aspect-Orient-Programming-in-NET

Comment: В данном случае как бы необходимо "навесить" вызовы Start и Stop перед и после каждого метода. Автоматически это делает профилировщик, но как я понял, по каким то причинам он не подходит. Значит, альтернатива — [T4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb126445(v=vs.120).aspx) перед компиляцией проекта, либо правка IL-кода после. Для последнего можно попробовать что-нибудь готовое, вроде [Aspects](https://github.com/steipete/Aspects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В .NET можно использовать Profiling API.
И, возможно, что CLR выводит информацию о вызовах в ETW (Event Tracing for Windows).
В nuget-пакете [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/) есть классы для работы с ETW.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить следующее:

```
void Measure(params Action[] callbacks)
{
    foreach (Action callback in callbacks)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        callback();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(callback.Method.Name + " : " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Логирование и что угодно добавьте по вкусу.
Вместо Action можно взять Func, в зависимости от сигнатуры методов.

Вызываем так:

```
Measure(Method1, Method2, Method3);
```